# OWASP ZAP can not test API

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I am currently trying to scan the API with zap. I downloaded the pet shop example from https://editor.swagger.io/ and set up a server with spring. Now I want to scan this API with a Jenkins build job.

My build job so far says:

```
docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly
docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t http://localhost:8080/v2/bla -f openapi
```

Via the URL I return the pet shop openapi definition as string. Loading from the local hard disk by C:... did not work.

I now have the following error and ask for help:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bla>docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly 
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from owasp/zap2docker-weekly
Digest: sha256:e4bee05e9cc3810ee5cf943d51c8ecdc477004d5af807c5af5598e8a1dcdb738
Status: Image is up to date for owasp/zap2docker-weekly:latest

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bla>docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t http://localhost:8080/v2/bla -f openapi 
2019-02-25 10:12:15,580 Params: ['zap-x.sh', '-daemon', '-port', '43255', '-host', '0.0.0.0', '-config', 'api.disablekey=true', '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.name=.*', '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.regex=true', '-addonupdate', '-addoninstall', 'pscanrulesBeta']
_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.
Feb 25, 2019 10:12:21 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
2019-02-25 10:12:26,820 Number of Imported URLs: 0
2019-02-25 10:12:26,820 Failed to import any URLs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/zap/zap-api-scan.py", line 397, in main
    raise NoUrlsException()
NoUrlsException
Found Java version 1.8.0_191
Available memory: 1980 MB
Using JVM args: -Xmx495m
227 [main] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.DaemonBootstrap  - OWASP ZAP D-2019-02-18 started 25/02/19 10:12:16 with home /home/zap/.ZAP_D/
275 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.common.AbstractParam  - Setting config api.disablekey = true was null
275 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.common.AbstractParam  - Setting config api.addrs.addr.name = .* was null
276 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.common.AbstractParam  - Setting config api.addrs.addr.regex = true was null
284 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.network.SSLConnector  - Reading supported SSL/TLS protocols...
284 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.network.SSLConnector  - Using a SSLEngine...
408 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.network.SSLConnector  - Done reading supported SSL/TLS protocols: [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
421 [main] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.option.OptionsParamCertificate  - Unsafe SSL renegotiation disabled.
865 [main] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - open start - state not modified
1008 [main] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache open start
1020 [main] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache open end
1081 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.control.ExtensionFactory  - Loading extensions
4239 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.control.ExtensionFactory  - Installed add-ons: [[id=accessControl, version=6.0.0], [id=alertFilters, version=8.0.0], [id=ascanrules, version=33.0.0], [id=ascanrulesBeta, version=25.0.0], [id=bruteforce, version=8.0.0], [id=coreLang, version=14.0.0], [id=cspscanner, version=7.0.0], [id=diff, version=9.0.0], [id=directorylistv1, version=4.0.0], [id=formhandler, version=3.0.0], [id=fuzz, version=11.0.0], [id=gettingStarted, version=10.0.0], [id=help, version=8.0.0], [id=hud, version=0.4.0], [id=importurls, version=6.0.0], [id=invoke, version=10.0.0], [id=jxbrowser, version=12.0.0], [id=jxbrowserlinux64, version=10.0.0], [id=jxbrowsermacos, version=10.0.0], [id=jxbrowserwindows, version=10.0.0], [id=jxbrowserwindows64, version=3.0.0], [id=onlineMenu, version=7.0.0], [id=openapi, version=13.0.0], [id=plugnhack, version=12.0.0], [id=portscan, version=9.0.0], [id=pscanrules, version=24.0.0], [id=pscanrulesBeta, version=19.0.0], [id=quickstart, version=26.0.0], [id=replacer, version=8.0.0], [id=reveal, version=3.0.0], [id=saverawmessage, version=5.0.0], [id=savexmlmessage, version=0.1.0], [id=scripts, version=25.0.0], [id=selenium, version=15.0.0], [id=sequence, version=6.0.0], [id=soap, version=4.0.0], [id=spiderAjax, version=23.0.0], [id=tips, version=6.0.0], [id=webdriverlinux, version=8.0.0], [id=webdrivermacos, version=8.0.0], [id=webdriverwindows, version=8.0.0], [id=websocket, version=19.0.0], [id=zest, version=29.0.0]]
4878 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.control.ExtensionFactory  - Extensions loaded
5089 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows ZAP to check for updates
5092 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Options Extension
5092 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Edit Menu Extension
5092 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Provides a rest based API for controlling and accessing ZAP
5263 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Session State Extension
5263 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Report Extension
5263 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing History Extension
5265 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Show hidden fields and enable disabled fields
5266 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Search messages for strings and regular expressions
5267 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Encode/Decode/Hash...
5267 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to intercept and modify requests and responses
5269 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Passive scanner
5389 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Script Passive Scan Rules
5389 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Stats Passive Scan Rule
5389 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: CSP Scanner
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: WSDL File Passive Scanner
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Application Error Disclosure
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Content-Type Header Missing
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Cookie No HttpOnly Flag
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Cookie Without Secure Flag
5390 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Secure Pages Include Mixed Content
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Private IP Disclosure
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Session ID in URL Rewrite
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: X-Frame-Options Header Scanner
5391 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Charset Mismatch
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Loosely Scoped Cookie
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Information Disclosure - Debug Error Messages
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Information Disclosure - Sensitive Information in URL
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Information Disclosure - Sensitive Information in HTTP Referrer Header
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Information Disclosure - Suspicious Comments
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Weak Authentication Method
5392 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Insecure JSF ViewState
5393 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: HTTP Parameter Override
5393 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan  - loaded passive scan rule: Viewstate Scanner
5407 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to view and manage alerts
5408 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Active scanner, heavily based on the original Paros active scanner, but with additional tests added
5417 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionSequence
5418 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Spider used for automatically finding URIs on a site
5424 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing A set of common popup menus for miscellaneous tasks
5425 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Forced browsing of files and directories using code from the OWASP DirBuster tool
5426 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Simple but effective port scanner
5426 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Manual Request Editor Extension
5427 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Compares 2 sessions and generates an HTML file showing the differences
5427 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Invoke external applications passing context related information such as URLs and parameters
5427 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Handles anti cross site request forgery (CSRF) tokens
5430 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Authentication Extension
5453 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.authentication.ExtensionAuthentication  - Loaded authentication method types: [Form-based Authentication, HTTP/NTLM Authentication, Manual Authentication, Script-based Authentication, JSON-based Authentication]
5454 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Creates a dynamic SSL certificate to allow SSL communications to be intercepted without warnings being generated by the browser
5455 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Logs errors to the Output tab in development mode only
5455 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Users Extension
5457 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Summarise and analyse FORM and URL parameters as well as cookies
5458 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Script integration
5487 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Scripting console, supports all JSR 223 scripting languages
5749 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Forced User Extension
5751 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Extension handling HTTP sessions
5753 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Zest is a specialized scripting language from Mozilla specifically designed to be used in security tools
5875 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionDiff
5876 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Post Table View Extension
5876 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Simple browser configuration
5876 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Session Management Extension
5879 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.sessions.ExtensionSessionManagement  - Loaded session management method types: [Cookie-based Session Management, HTTP Authentication Session Management]
5879 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Form Table View Extension
5880 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Capture messages from WebSockets with the ability to set breakpoints.
5898 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to import a file containing URLs which ZAP will access, adding them to the Sites tree
5898 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to import a WSDL file containing operations which ZAP will access, adding them to the Sites tree.
5899 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Core UI related functionality.
5899 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Authorization Extension
5900 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing AJAX Spider, uses Crawljax
5902 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Provides WebDrivers to control several browsers using Selenium and includes HtmlUnit browser.
5909 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Manages the local proxy configurations
5910 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Add-on that adds a set of tools for testing access control in web applications.
5910 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Handles adding Global Excluded URLs
5910 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Adds menu item to refresh the Sites tree
5910 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing OWASP ZAP User Guide
5910 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Provides a URL suitable for calling from target sites
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to configure which extensions are loaded when ZAP starts
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Combined HTTP Panels Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Hex View Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Image View Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Large Request View Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Large Response View Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Query Table View Extension
5913 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing HTTP Panel Syntax Highlighter View Extension
5914 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Adds support for configurable keyboard shortcuts for all of the ZAP menus.
5914 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Active and passive rule configuration
5916 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Statistics
5918 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.stats.ExtensionStats  - Start recording in memory stats
5919 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Context alert rules filter
5920 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing This extension allows a user to change the default values used by ZAP Spiders.
5923 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionJxBrowserWindows64
5923 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtSelJxBrowserWindows64
5923 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionSaveRawHttpMessage
5923 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows you to spider and import OpenAPI (Swagger) definitions 
5937 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Translations of the core language files
5937 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Active Scan Rules
5937 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing The Online menu links
5938 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionJxBrowser
5938 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Content Security Policy Scanner
5938 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionSaveXMLHttpMessage
5938 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Quick Start panel 
5938 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Launch browsers proxying through ZAP
5940 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionJxBrowserMaxOS
5940 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtSelJxBrowserMacOs
5944 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Active Scan Rules - beta
5945 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Provides the foundation for concrete message types (for example, HTTP, WebSockets) expose fuzzer implementations.
5947 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows to fuzz HTTP messages.
5947 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Passive Scan Rules
5948 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing The ZAP Getting Started Guide
5948 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Tips and Tricks
5948 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionJxBrowserWindows
5948 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtSelJxBrowserWindows
5948 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows to fuzz WebSocket messages.
5949 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionJxBrowserLinux64
5949 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtSelJxBrowserLinux64
5963 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Easy way to replace strings in requests and responses
5971 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Heads Up Display
6014 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing ExtensionHUDlaunch
6015 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Passive Scan Rules - beta
6248 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.callback.ExtensionCallback  - Started callback server on 0.0.0.0:43579
6249 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.dynssl.ExtensionDynSSL  - Creating new root CA certificate
7285 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.dynssl.ExtensionDynSSL  - New root CA certificate created
8288 [ZAP-daemon] ERROR org.parosproxy.paros.CommandLine  - Check for updates call failed
9289 [ZAP-daemon] ERROR org.parosproxy.paros.CommandLine  - Check for updates call failed
9290 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.DaemonBootstrap  - ZAP is now listening on 0.0.0.0:43255
10537 [ZAP-ProxyThread-6] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.ExtensionOpenApi  - Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:728)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:449)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(HttpSender.java:360)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(HttpSender.java:592)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:551)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:529)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:518)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:432)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.network.Requestor.getResponseBody(Requestor.java:96)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.ExtensionOpenApi.importOpenApiDefinition(ExtensionOpenApi.java:172)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.OpenApiAPI.handleApiAction(OpenApiAPI.java:95)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:449)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:456)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:318)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10544 [ZAP-ProxyThread-6] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API  - Bad request to API endpoint [/JSON/openapi/action/importUrl/] from [127.0.0.1]:
Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value (illegal_parameter) : url
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.OpenApiAPI.handleApiAction(OpenApiAPI.java:105)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:449)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:456)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:318)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment above i have a working solution,

Changing the build job to the following solved my problem

```
docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly
docker run --network="host" -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t http://docker.for.win.localhost:8080/v2/bla -f openapi
```

By using `http://docker.for.win.localhost` i can access the host network. If anyone needs to adapt this solution for other platforms, there are different types for different platforms e.g. `docker.for.mac.localhost`

Comment: Works for me even with adding `--network="host"`. Without any extra `docker.for.mac.localhost`

Answer (score 2):

You are running ZAP in docker and trying to connect to http://localhost:8080/v2/bla
However, unless you've actually started your app in the docker container it wont be accessible via localhost within the docker image.
You can confirm this but opening a shell in the ZAP docker image and running:

> curl http://localhost:8080/v2/bla

You will need to configure docker so that you can access services running on in the containing machine and use the right address to access them. A quite google indicated that there are various ways of doing this depending on what platform you are using.